# Show always Current year valuein SharePoint List drop down

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

How to show default current year value in SharePoint list drop down when users clicking New form.

For Example.

Year Drop Down List contains 2017,2018,2019,2020

Expected Result: 
Year Drop Down selected current year value of 2019

Thanks

Comment: Is it a choice field? If so you’d just set its default to 2019

Answer (score 0):

Change the default value to "Calculated Value" and put below formula:

```
=TEXT(Today,”YYYY”)
```

It will always selects current year dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

We can add the code below into script editor web part in new form page to achieve it. Note: you need modify the column name in the code below to make it works.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var columnName="Year";
    var currentYear=(new Date()).getFullYear();
    $("select[title='"+columnName+"']").val(currentYear);
})
</script>
```

[image]